# Spark DataFrame - select list of columns using Java API

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to select List of columns from the DataFrame using Java API.

**Sample Java Code:**

```java
List<String> colList = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "column1", "column2", "column3" });
df.selectExpr((String[])colList.toArray()).show();
```

In Java API, I have to use `selectExpr` instead of `select`. Is there any other way of selecting list of columns using Java API.

But in Scala, I can do something like below.

**Sample Scala Code:**

```scala
val colList = List("column1", "column2", "column3")
df.select(colList.head, colList.tail: _*).show
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use array of `String`:

```
String[] colList =  { "column1", "column2", "column3" };
String first = colList[0];
String[] rest =  Arrays.copyOfRange(colList, 1, colList.length);

logData.select(first, rest);
```

or array of `Column`:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;

Column[] colList =  { col("column1"), col("column2"), col("column3") };
logData.select(colList);
```

Comment: first approach is not array of string, you are programmatically building first and rest and also second approach is again something we need to build it from the list of column names as String.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a lovely and straightforward way. NOT.

Comment: @Alper,  nice. My requirement is, columns will change, say sometimes I get col1, col2 and sometimes I get col1,col2,col3. How to dynamically do this in second approach. because I need to add column alias also from params. appreciate your inputs on this.